# FormsIdentity and FormsAuthenticationTicket in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, .net-4.6.1, .net-core-2.1

I am migrating one library class from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to Core 2.1.

The library uses types **FormsAuthenticationTicket** and **FormsIdentity** which are defined in .NET Framework namespace **System.Web.Security**. Unfortunately Core does not implement the System.Web.Security.

Do you know whether there is something equivalent in .NET Core? Ideally I want to use an assembly which defines exactly the same types.